# BASH: find duplicate files (MAC/LINUX compatible)

Tags: linux, mac, bash

I am looking for a bash script which is compatible with Mac, to find duplicate files in a directory.

Comment: Please define "duplicate" - Binary equivalent, text equivalent, same size, same name?

Comment: This stuff also looks useful, finding dupes with a single line, even considering a check for same size first. http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3555/find-duplicate-files-based-on-size-first-then-md5-hash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know about Mac compatibility, but [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a5dab2e76b0aab5ecc93367c59fa8067f73ab320/scripts/duplicates.sh) Works For Me(TM):

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -n "$1" ] || exit 1
exec 9< <( find "$1" -type f -print0 )
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    file_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
    file_path="${file_path%x}"
    exec 8< <( find "$1" -type f -not -path "$file_path" -print0 )
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 8 OTHER
    do
        cmp --quiet -- "$REPLY" "$OTHER"
        case $? in
            0)
                echo -n "cmp -- "
                printf %q "${REPLY}"
                echo -n ' '
                printf %q "${OTHER}"
                echo ""
                break
                ;;
            2)
                echo "\`cmp\` failed!"
                exit 2
                ;;
            *)
                :
                ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

The result is a set of commands you can run to check that the result is correct :)

Edit: The last version works with really weird filenames like:

```
$'/tmp/--$`\\! *@ \a\b\E\E\f\r\t\v\\"\' \n'
```

Comment: Nice work, but I see three issues: 1) this is O(n^2), meaning it will be really slow on big dirs. 2) it seems it will do both checks 'does a = b' and 'does b = a'  3) your check for same file name means it won't check at all if the file exists in both a dir and subdir. e.g. DIR/fred and DIR/subdir/fred will not be compared.hows u

Comment: Not sure if this is a me thing or if this script is just very memory intensive, but I tried running the script on a very large directory (content-wise) and got a memory allocation error that killed the continued execution of the script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

it works for me on my mac, you will catch the duplicate file by their md5 value:

```
find ./ -type f -exec md5 {} \; | awk -F '=' '{print $2 "\t" $1}' | sort
```

Comment: after `sort` if you add `| uniq -d -f 1 -s 33` it will output just the duplicates

Answer (score 3):

This will find files under a dir with dupes.  It's pretty raw, but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

CKSUMPROG=md5sum
TMPFILE=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/duplicate.$$
trap "rm -f $TMPFILE" EXIT INT

if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
    echo "usage $0 directory" >2
    exit 1
fi

PRINTBLANK=
# dump fingerprints from all target files into a tmpfile
find "$1" -type f 2> /dev/null | xargs $CKSUMPROG  > $TMPFILE 2> /dev/null

# get fingerprints from tmpfile, get the ones with duplicates which means multiple files with same contents
for DUPEMD5 in $(cut -d ' ' -f 1 $TMPFILE | sort  | uniq -c | sort -rn | grep -v '^  *1 ' | sed 's/^ *[1-9][0-9]* //')
do
    if [ -z "$PRINTBLANK" ]
    then
        PRINTBLANK=1
    else
        echo
        echo
    fi

    grep "^${DUPEMD5} " $TMPFILE | gawk '{print $2}'
done
```

Comment: Clever. Too bad it starts over calculating those checksums everytime. I guess that part is left to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If only interested in files in the current directory (as indicated by OP), then this is the simpliest.  For linux and Windows (msys - tested, or MinGW or Cygwin with any with GnuWin32).  This will list **all** duplicates.

```
md5sum * | sort | uniq -D -w 32
```

For BSD/Mac OS X (it will list only the **first** duplicate)

```
md5 -r * | sort | uniq -d -w 32
```

Comment: I you want support for subfolders also: `md5sum \`find -type f\` | sort | uniq -D -w 32`

Comment: Not this will fail for a file with spaces in its names. In this case `find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' +` would do the right thing instead of `md5sum \`find -type f\``.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend the commandline called `fdupes`
https://macappstore.org/fdupes/

You can run/scan directories like so:

```
fdupes -r /directory/to/scan/for/file/dups

# You can redirect the results to a file
fdupes -r /directory/to/scan/for/file/dups > /tmp/duplicates.txt

# You can also delete flag ( -d ) while you find
# I less prefer this option
# I add this flag only after I scan with my eyes
# the results from the above command ..
fdupes -r -d /directory/to/scan/for/file/dups
```

Comment: It's best to give a summary instead of just relying on the link.